# Find the direction where the rate of change of the function is 0

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the function: $f(x,y) = 2x/(x-y)$

I've worked out my partial derivatives to be:

$f_x = -2y/(x-y)^2$

$f_y=2x/(x-y)^2$

I want to find the direction in which the rate of change of the function is $0$ (so essentially the direction in which the gradient of the function is $0$).

I feel like this isn't too hard to do and I'm just overthinking it. In a previous part of the question I was asked to find the directional derivative when the direction was $v=(4,3)$ and I found the unit vector to be $4/5i +3/5j$ (I got this by doing $v/||v||$). Am I supposed to use this unit vector in some way or is it irrelevant?

Any support would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found,

$\nabla f(x,y) = \left(-\cfrac{2y}{(x-y)^2}, \cfrac{2x}{(x-y)^2}\right)$

when $x \ne y$

So at any given point $(x_0, y_0)$, the direction that will give zero rate of change will be perpendicular to the gradient vector. Hence the direction is,

$\pm\left(\cfrac{2x_0}{(x_0-y_0)^2}, \cfrac{2y_0}{(x_0-y_0)^2}\right)$

You can convert it into unit vector.

Comment: So my answer is just perpendicular to my gradient? So it's $(2x/(x-y)^2, 2y/(x-y)^2)$?

Comment: It can be both $\pm$ sign. Also we usually write direction using unit vector so you can convert it into unit vector which comes to $\pm\left(\cfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \cfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$

Comment: Ok, I understand, yeah I was overthinking it, thanks for the clarification

Comment: you are welcome