# Find the direction in which the directional derivative is 0

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I've asked a very similar question to this before but a few days later I'm looking at another question and am still slightly confused.

I have the function: $f(x,y) = x/(x+y)$

I want to the find the direction in which the directional derivative is $0$ at the point $(1,2)$.

I started by calculating my partial derivatives (in order to obtain the gradient) and I got:

$f_x = y/(x+y)^2$

$f_y = -x/(x+y)^2$

So the gradient of $f$ is $(y/(x+y)^2 , -x/(x+y)^2)$

I plugged in $(1,2)$ to get the direction where the directional derivative is maximal (it asks this earlier on in the question) and got $(2/9 , -1/9)$

In my previous post on here someone helped me before and told me that the directional derivative will be $0$ when perpendicular to the gradient, so I tried this. However, I either found the perpendicular incorrectly (which is probably what's wrong here) or the method doesn't work here.

I found the perpendicular to be $\pm (x/(x+y)^2 , y/(x+y)^2)$ but when I plug my $x$ and $y$ values into this I don't get the correct answer (I have the solutions sheet only, no working out given, and the solutions should be $(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$).

If anyone could show me what I'm doing wrong and the method for calculating the perpendiculars (if needed) it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

(The old question, for reference: [Find the direction where the rate of change of the function is 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4206104/928623) )

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I'll add it in now. The initial gradient I've found should be correct, it's the same one in the solution sheet, I think where I've gone wrong is finding the perpendicular to my gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directional derivative is indeed perpendicular to the gradient.

Since the gradient of your function is $\left(\frac29,-\frac19\right)$
at $(1,2),$ you can rotate that vector by a right angle in either direction to obtain either $\left(\frac19,\frac29\right)$ or $\left(-\frac19,-\frac29\right).$

But if a vector $v$ points in a particular direction, so does $kv$ for any positive scalar multiplier $k$.
If you multiply each of the vectors $\left(\frac19,\frac29\right)$
and $\left(-\frac19,-\frac29\right)$ by the scalar $9$ you get
$(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2).$

By the same token you can multiply $(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$ each by
$\frac19$ and get the vectors $\left(\frac19,\frac29\right)$
and $\left(-\frac19,-\frac29\right),$ which point in the same directions as
$(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2).$

Unless there are additional restrictions on the answer,
such as a requirement that the magnitude by $\sqrt5$ or that the magnitude of the first component by $1,$ I don't see how $(1,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$
can be said to be the **only** correct ways to write the answer.

On the other hand, the only correct answers are the **direction** of
$(1,2)$ and the **direction** of $(-1,-2),$
expressed in some suitable ways
(for example, expressed as the directions of
$\left(\frac19,\frac29\right)$ and $\left(-\frac19,-\frac29\right)$).
Is it possible that that is how the answer key was intended to be interpreted?

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes perfect sense. I doubt I would be marked wrong if I put $(1/9,2/9)$ or $(-1/9 , -2/9)$ since they are correct answers. I think my lecturer put this as the solution on the sheet just to make us aware that there is a way to "simplify" (I guess) the answer or at least get an answer that isn't a fraction and maybe "looks nicer" I really have no idea :) . Thanks again